# How to pass multi array to composer laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5

I'm trying to pass 2 arrays to a base view in laravel but I can't find the way to figure it out. It works well with 1 array, but can't with 2 arrays.
I have a sidebar for a commercer website, which will display list of catetogories and list of shops. I use composer to handle it as a base view, but I can't pass 2 arrays of categories and shops.
This is my composer class:

```
class SidebarComposer
{

    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        $categories = array();
        $categories[0] = "Cate 1";
        $categories[1] = "Cate 2";
        $categories[2] = "Cate 3";
        $categories[3] = "Cate 4";
        $categories[4] = "Cate 5";
        $categories[5] = "Cate 6";

        $shops = array();
        $shops[0] = "Shop 0";
        $shops[1] = "shops 1"

        $view->with('categories',$categories)->with('shops',$shops);
    }
}
```

Here is my view (sidebar.blade.php)

> ```
> @for ($i = 0; $i < count($categories); $i++)
>     <div class="panel panel-default">
>     <div class="panel-heading">
>       <h4 class="panel-title"><a href="">{{$categories[$i]}}</a></h4>
>     </div>
> </div>
> @endfor
> @for ($i = 0; $i < count($shops); $i++)
>             <li><a href="{{url('')}}"> <span class="pull-right"></span>{{$shops[$i]}}</a></li>
> @endfor
> ```

I have no experiences with laravel. Please help me, thanks very much.

Comment: I don't have a laravel install to try this out, have you tried something like `->with(array('categories'=>$categories, 'shops'=>$shops));`?

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfectly, but I've just realized that my way works. I just miss ";" at the end of array, I've wasted 2 hours for nothing. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use an array to trans many value to blade.

hope it helps.

```
$view->with(['categories' => $categories, 'shops' => $shops]);
```

when you have to many values, use this

```
$data['categories'] = $categories;
$data['shops'] = $shops;
$data[...] = ...
...
$view->with($data);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfectly, but I've just realized that my way works. I just miss ";" at the end of array, I've wasted 2 hours for nothing. Anyway, thanks for your help.